# Composer fails on capistrano deploy "phpseclib/bootstrap.php: failed to open stream"

Tags: laravel, composer-php, capistrano, phpseclib

So, running cap production deploy now fails and gives me this log:

```
    DEBUG [d8e9f9b4]    Generating autoload files
     DEBUG [d8e9f9b4]   > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
     DEBUG [d8e9f9b4]   PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: require(/some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:55
    Stack trace:
    #0 /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(55): Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(/srv/us...', '/path/...', 55, Array)
    #1 /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(55): require()
    #2 /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(45): composerRequire28a339249b76e8c9bd2081b3b12636da('decc78cc4436b12...', '/path/...')
    #3 /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit28a339249b76e8c9bd2081b3b12636da::getLoader()
    #4 /some_path/releases/201611011006 in /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 55
     DEBUG [d8e9f9b4]   
    Warning: Uncaught ErrorException: require(/some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:55
    Stack trace:
    #0 /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(55): Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(/path/...', '/path/...', 55, Array)
    #1 /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(55): require()
    #2 /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(45): composerRequire28a339249b76e8c9bd2081b3b12636da('decc78cc4436b12...', '/path/...')
    #3 /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit28a339249b76e8c9bd2081b3b12636da::getLoader()
    #4 /some_path/releases/201611011006 in /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 55
     DEBUG [d8e9f9b4]   PHP Fatal error:  composerRequire28a339249b76e8c9bd2081b3b12636da(): Failed opening required '/some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/opt/sp/php7.0/lib/php') in /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 55
     DEBUG [d8e9f9b4]   
    Fatal error: composerRequire28a339249b76e8c9bd2081b3b12636da(): Failed opening required '/some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/opt/sp/php7.0/lib/php') in /some_path/releases/20161101100659/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 55
```

It worked fine before I changed JWT lib from 0.5.9 to 1.0.0.alpha and added laravelconnect/remote package.

Note: this all works on my local machine. I've no idea why phpsec doesn't have bootstrap.php file in it. On my local machine it does have it.

Comment: give permission to storage

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not allowed to do that

Comment: Is there a specific part you want to see?